# How to know from which line within a function an exception is occuring in Java?

Tags: java

When developing an application, we normally use different functions from different classes. Now a function can be written in a way, where only the different functions are called. So 
I just want to know suppose I am having a function where I have called some other functions and also having unique code in that function. So how I will know for a bigger project, that from which line for a particular function, exception is occurring in Java.

At most, right now I can detect only from which function exception is occurring. But I need specific portion(specific line) of that function where the exception is occurring.

Any helpful answer will be appreciated.......Thanks in advance......!!!!!

Comment: You look at the stack trace that **should** be coded to be included when any exception is thrown.

Comment: Do you want to obtain this piece of information programmatically when handling the exception or only to view this information when debugging?

Comment: Hi,Andrei                                                                      I need to obtain the information pro grammatically. Is it possible to get this message in a customized way ?

Answer (score 2):

```
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The rest of answers written here are perfectly relevant and true, but there is a little gap.  You must remember to include in your binary files the relevant debug information, or if not, the JVM will not know which line number caused the exception.  Remember to set the debug flag when compiling your code, have a look at this from the javac help:

```
C:\>\j2sdk1.5.0\bin\javac

Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
 -g                     Generate all debugging info
 -g:none                Generate no debugging info
 -g:{lines,vars,source} Generate only some debugging info
```

You would need to compile with `javac -g xxx.java`, or at least `javac -g:lines xxx.java` in order to have that information on execution time.  If you compile your code by any other means (Eclipse or any other IDE compiler, ant, maven, gradle...) you should have a look at your automation tool compiler doc in order to know how to instruct its compiler to generate debug information along with your binaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
//your code that may have error
}
catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

suppose there's error occur then it will show something like this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
```

it means error at `line number 16` in Book.java.

[look this article](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_stack_trace.html)

Answer (score 0):

You look at the stacktrace. For example:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java)
        at FooBar.test(FooBar.java:19)
        at FooBar.main(FooBar.java:7)
```

To get the execution order you have to read it from bottom to top.

Here

- the program starts at the method `main()` of class `FooBar`
- `main()` calls the method `FooBar.test()` in line 7 of `FooBar.java`
- `test()` calls the `FileInputStream` constructor in line 19 of `FooBar.java`
- the `FileInputStream` constructor throws an `FileNotFoundException`

You can print the stacktrace of an exception using:

```
try {
  ..
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```